# Why do I get the exiled queen ending in Undertale when I did a pacifist route?

Tags: undertale

Why do I get the exiled queen ending in Undertale when I haven't killed anyone? All I've done is give myself the Real Knife and Locket at the end of the game.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out, it was because I had not completed the true lab portion of Undertale.